# Inheriting android style framework for UI?

Tags: user-interface, android, android-styles, android-framework

I am reading a design presentation to try and learn some more about android UI. On slide 17, it explains to inherit styles.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bz3qX4EBhUvwZWlHekI3Y0wxSUk/view?sle=true

The developer then says to "Use the framework" and access styles to style your UI. For example, he uses

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.light" />
```

for sdk versions 11+ in the styles.xml folder. And in the manifest he then sets the theme to "MyTheme". After, he says to reference styles from the current theme, such as

```
<TextView
     style="?android:ListSeparatorTextViewStyle"
     ...
     ... />
```

However, this gives an error that says missing styles. So I researched this and instead found a different way of implementing this as

```
@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.TextView.ListSeparator
```

which gave me an error saying the resource is not public.

**So my question is, how can I organize my style.xml, manifest, and layouts to implement android styles like the ones above? What do I need to check to be able to access these styles? Where can I learn about proper organization of these folders and style inheritance?** I have tried reading documentation on the android website, but cannot find much help anywhere else. Any advice on where to find other sources on sample code on proper ways to design UI are welcome as well. Thanks for any help.